# Position relative makes divs overlapped

Tags: html, css, position, height, overlapping

I have created a content-template with ftl that generates timeline.Below you will see two timelines. I had to use position relative because i want to have the box always on the same position.A single timeline on page works well but when I add another html element blow it then I have overlap problem. I tried to solve this problem by givin min-height:340px for h-timeline-container but if a user add a long textx or big image there is still overlap problem. If I give min-height:auto it wont help as well.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GCRGYZ1AD8M5

```
<div class="trij_ h-timeline-container">
<ol class="h-timeline-wrap">
    <li class="trij_ h-timeline-point" style="background-color: rgb(0, 39, 118); border-color: rgb(0, 39, 118);"><span class="point-text">
        1
    </span><span class="trij_ point-arrow-shade" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</span> <span class="trij_ point-arrow" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <span class="trij_ point-details" style="display: block;"><div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-7">
    <h3>Headline 1</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    </div>
<div class="col-sm-5 my-2">
    <img class="h-timeline-img" alt="" data-fileentryid="586641705" src="/image/journal/article?img_id=587028236&amp;t=1583916613666&amp;fileName=hays_socialmedia-600.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
    </span>
    <li class="trij_ h-timeline-point" style="background-color: rgb(0, 159, 218); border-color: rgb(0, 159, 218);"><span class="point-text">
        2
    </span><span class="trij_ point-arrow-shade" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span> <span class="trij_ point-arrow" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <span class="trij_ point-details" style="display: none;"><div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h3>Headline 2</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </span>
    <li class="trij_ h-timeline-point" style="background-color: rgb(0, 159, 218); border-color: rgb(0, 159, 218);"><span class="point-text">
        3
    </span><span class="trij_ point-arrow-shade" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span> <span class="trij_ point-arrow" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <span class="trij_ point-details" style="display: none;"><div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h3>Headline 2</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.<br><br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </span>


</ol>
</div>
<style type="text/css">

.h-timeline-icons{
    margin-left: -2px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.h-timeline-container{
    min-height:340px;
     margin:30px 0;
}
.h-timeline-img{
    max-height:250px;
}
.h-wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
ol.h-timeline-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
    height: 3px;
    background: #eeeeee;
}

ol.h-timeline-wrap::before {
    left: -5px;
}
ol.h-timeline-wrap::after {
    right: -10px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid #9b2;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/* ---- Timeline elements ---- */

li.h-timeline-point {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: -16px;
    left: -15px;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 0;
    font: bold 14px arial;
    border: 4px solid #009FDA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #009FDA;
}
li.h-timeline-point:hover {
    background-color: #002776 !important;
    border-color: #002776 !important;
}


.point-text {
    right: -8.5px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 25px;
    top: 1px;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
}

/* ---- Details ---- */

.trij_ .point-details {
    position: absolute;
    right: 4%;
    top: 53px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #002776;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #fff;
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 90%;
    z-index:-1;
}


.h-timeline-point:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.point-arrow {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -4px;
    top: 40px;
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #002776;
}
.point-arrow-shade{
    display: block;
    top: 43px;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: -4px;
    content: "";
    z-index: 2;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {


}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {


}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .h-timeline-container {
     min-height: 540px;
    }

  .trij_ .point-details{
      right:2%;
      width:93%;
  }

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .h-timeline-img{
      max-height:200px;
    }
}
</style>

<script>
$('li.trij_.h-timeline-point').on('click',function(){
  $('.trij_.point-details, .trij_.point-arrow, .trij_.point-arrow-shade').css('display', 'none');
  $('li.trij_.h-timeline-point').css('background-color', '#009FDA');
  $('li.trij_.h-timeline-point').css('border-color', '#009FDA');
  if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none'){
     $(this).css('background-color', '#002776');
     $(this).css('border-color', '#002776');
     $(this).next().css('display', 'block');
     $(this).children().next().css('display', 'block');
     $(this).children().next().next().css('display', 'block');
  }
});
$('li.trij_.h-timeline-point').first().click();
</script>

<div class="rfgi_ h-timeline-container">
<ol class="h-timeline-wrap">
    <li class="rfgi_ h-timeline-point" style="background-color: rgb(0, 39, 118); border-color: rgb(0, 39, 118);"><span class="point-text">
        1
    </span><span class="rfgi_ point-arrow-shade" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</span> <span class="rfgi_ point-arrow" style="display: block;">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <span class="rfgi_ point-details" style="display: block;"><div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h3>Headline</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </span>
    <li class="rfgi_ h-timeline-point" style="background-color: rgb(0, 159, 218); border-color: rgb(0, 159, 218);"><span class="point-text">
        2
    </span><span class="rfgi_ point-arrow-shade" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span> <span class="rfgi_ point-arrow" style="display: none;">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <span class="rfgi_ point-details" style="display: none;"><div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h3>Headline 2</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </span>


</ol>
</div>
<style type="text/css">

.h-timeline-icons{
    margin-left: -2px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.h-timeline-container{
    min-height:340px;
     margin:30px 0;
}
.h-timeline-img{
    max-height:250px;
}
.h-wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
ol.h-timeline-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
    height: 3px;
    background: #eeeeee;
}

ol.h-timeline-wrap::before {
    left: -5px;
}
ol.h-timeline-wrap::after {
    right: -10px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid #9b2;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/* ---- Timeline elements ---- */

li.h-timeline-point {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: -16px;
    left: -15px;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 0;
    font: bold 14px arial;
    border: 4px solid #009FDA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #009FDA;
}
li.h-timeline-point:hover {
    background-color: #002776 !important;
    border-color: #002776 !important;
}


.point-text {
    right: -8.5px;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 25px;
    top: 1px;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
}

/* ---- Details ---- */

.rfgi_ .point-details {
    position: absolute;
    right: 4%;
    top: 53px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #002776;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #fff;
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 90%;
    z-index:-1;
}


.h-timeline-point:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.point-arrow {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -4px;
    top: 40px;
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #002776;
}
.point-arrow-shade{
    display: block;
    top: 43px;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: -4px;
    content: "";
    z-index: 2;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {


}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {


}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .h-timeline-container {
     min-height: 540px;
    }

  .rfgi_ .point-details{
      right:2%;
      width:93%;
  }

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .h-timeline-img{
      max-height:200px;
    }
}
</style>
<script>
$('li.rfgi_.h-timeline-point').on('click',function(){
  $('.rfgi_.point-details, .rfgi_.point-arrow, .rfgi_.point-arrow-shade').css('display', 'none');
  $('li.rfgi_.h-timeline-point').css('background-color', '#009FDA');
  $('li.rfgi_.h-timeline-point').css('border-color', '#009FDA');
  if ($(this).next().css('display') == 'none'){
     $(this).css('background-color', '#002776');
     $(this).css('border-color', '#002776');
     $(this).next().css('display', 'block');
     $(this).children().next().css('display', 'block');
     $(this).children().next().next().css('display', 'block');
  }
});
$('li.rfgi_.h-timeline-point').first().click();
</script>
```

Comment: This is my try with getting the height of the inner text and setting that as the minimum height of the element.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GCRM9YM5OMX0

Comment: Hmm interesting solution, thanks. But how can I add this on page load because this works just on click,so there is still overlapping on page load